# Глобальная обработка Нажатий мыши Java

Tags: java, mouse-event

Хотелось бы обработать нажатие мыши не только в своем приложении, но и глобально. Есть такой код :

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            if (flag == false) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
};
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как можно сделать так, чтобы прослушивались нажатия мыши в других приложениях.

Comment: в других в смысле вне виртуальной машины?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , да.

Comment: на чистой java это сделать нельзя

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а с помощью чего можно? Какие инструменты можете предложить?

Comment: изучите API той системы где вы хотите это сделать

Comment: @MikhailVaysman хотелось бы кросс-платформенно, но вообще хочу под Linux. А где можно посмотреть этот API?

Comment: кроссплатформенность в java достигается тем, что программа работает в внутри виртуальной машины и все, что находится вне ВМ как бы не существует. вот напримре документация https://developer.gnome.org/references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему использованием библиотеки [jnativehook](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.1stleg/jnativehook/2.0.2).

Вот пример кода для обработки событий:

```
public class Main implements NativeMouseInputListener {


    @Override
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent nativeMoPressuseEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, NativeHookException {

        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        Main main = new Main();
        GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(main);
        GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseMotionListener(main);

    }
}
```